# bigquery error: "Could not parse '41.66666667' as INT64"

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I am attempting to create a table using a .tsv file in BigQuery, but keep getting the following error:

"Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '41.66666667' as INT64 for field Team_Percentage (position 8) starting at location 14419658 with message 'Unable to parse'"

I am not sure what to do as I am completely new to this.

Here is a file with the first 100 lines of the full data:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/25c18d56eb863bafcfdb5956a46449c920220502031838/f5ed2f

Here are the steps I am currently taking to to create the table:

https://i.gyazo.com/07815cec446b5c0869d7c9323a7fdee4.mp4

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: It means your data is not compatible with datatype `INT64`. If you are creating a table you should change the datatype on the schema to either `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT64`. See [BQ datatypes reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric_types).

Comment: How exactly do I do this?

Comment: How are you creating the table in the first place? Can you include that in your question?

Comment: @RiccoD Please let me know if the edits I just made are what you need! It's my first time using and asking a bigquery question, sorry.

Comment: Instead of clicking "Auto detect" you should manually define your schema so you won't be encountering this error. In the schema define the column name along with its correct data type. You can check the link I previously sent as a reference on what data type you should use per column.

Comment: @RiccoD Sorry, could you guide me? I checked out the link but it seemed to just list the data types and not explain how I would actually make the schema. And since I was previously detecting the schema automatically, what does that mean for all the other columns? Here is what I have so far for adding the FLOAT type: https://gyazo.com/35ec9c1d65c42335b60165cd68f1e2ab

Comment: What you did is correct. You now need to manually define the remaining columns as well. You can check this as reference as well https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#console

Comment: @RiccoD Thanks, had a look at that now. What should I do in the event that a column does not adhere to "A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore."? In this case, I have two trouble columns, "Song/Album" and "Earnings (USD)"

Comment: Well your only option is to adhere with the accepted column names. AFAIK there are no workarounds to bypass those checks.

Comment: @RiccoD I see... I will rename them now then and retry creating the table

Comment: @RiccoD Should I be parsing this as a string instead? https://gyazo.com/b0a5c0a9394ff9d2df12265e3596b27e

Comment: Most likely yes

Comment: @RiccoD Thanks for the help, I think I should be good from here on out ^^ not sure how to mark this as solved unless someone provides an answer however haha

Comment: I'll post it an answer in a few, just so it is clear on what is the fix for this. You can upvote/accept it just so the answer is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed with OP (@dan), the error encountered is caused by selecting `Auto detect` when creating a table using a .tsv file as the source.

The fix for this is to manually create a schema and define the data type for each column properly. For more reference on using schema in BQ see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#console).